# Animated plotly-express graph not showing up in jupyter-lab

Tags: plotly, jupyter-lab, plotly-express

The following example produces an animated graph that can be displayed with `jupyter notebook`, but in `jupyter-lab` the graph does not show up.

```
%pylab inline
import plotly.express as px
gapminder = px.data.gapminder()
px.scatter(gapminder, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country",
           size="pop", color="continent", hover_name="country",
           log_x=True, size_max=55, range_x=[100,100000], range_y=[25,90])
```

Using plotly 4.0.0 and plotly_express 0.4.0.

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For JupyterLab support there are couple of additional installation steps: https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/#jupyterlab-support-python-35

Edit: we've consolidated our troubleshooting steps into one handy guide at https://plotly.com/python/troubleshooting/

Comment: Thanks for making these useful guides @nicolaskruchten, however I am encountering the same issue with Jupyterlab 3.0.5 and have opened an issue https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3052

Answer (score 2):

**Follow the below Steps to show plots in jupyter notebook, Please follow the below link to find more details on the below commands and thier usange :**
[JupyterLab Support for plotely](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/#jupyterlab-support-python-35)

1. `pip install jupyterlab "ipywidgets>=7.5"`
2. `jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly@4.14.3`
3. `jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager`
4. `jupyter lab`

Comment: I just want to say, I didn't run third one but right now, I can see the output of the code.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of Nbextension. In configurable nbextensions. You have to disable `jupyterlab-plotly/extension` and `plotlywidget/extension`. After that restart the notebook. I hope it will work.[here is image of disable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vaej6.png)